# arithmetic exception numeric overflow or string truncation string right truncation firebird, When inserting into a table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

This is the part of my query that it posing the problem:
on an insert from table1 to table2

```
insert into table2 (COLUMNS......,LOCAL)
    SELECT COLUMNS,....., IIF( M.COUNTRY=213 , (((P.PRICE *@QUANTITY)*20)/100), 0) as LOCAL
    where .....
```

if M.COUNTRY is Numeric it works fine else if String ex:FRA it Fails with the title's message.
M.COUNTRY datatype is VARCHAR(20)
LOCAL Colmumn is of datatype NUMERIC(8,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem resides exactly, I have another column with M.COUNTRY that I want to insert it's value from a VARCHAR(20) to another column of CHAR(1), my mistake obviously it will fail as it does not fit the size. Firebird was confusing me as the error appears on the line of the query I posted first, not the one causing the issue it misguided me to debug it.

Comment: _"Firebird was confusing me as the error appears on the line of the query I posted first, not the one causing the issue it misguided me to debug it."_ Statements are executed individually, so the line reported in the error was the line from the start of that statement.

Comment: @Mark Rorreveel Thank you , i understand but the error line that was given was not of the statement that was raising the error, i know that firebird has a lot to do to improve  debuging based on raised errors, but it's a great rdbms, and it's free.

Comment: Unless you are executing from an `execute block` or a stored procedure, the statements are executed individually, and the error line and column number reported are for each statement individually.